# Declaring Variable in Controller

Tags: angularjs

In the following Angular code, why must I declare `$scope.myName` before setting it?

```
myModule.controller('Controller', function($scope) {   
  $scope.myName;

  $scope.setName = function(name) {
         $scope.myName = name;   
  }; 
}
```

Comment: You don't have to.  What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with function scopes in Javascript right. If you dont need to use myName in the scope of the Controller you dont have to declare it. Otherwise its scope is within the setName function.

As per my understanding of javascript scopes.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is breaking if you don't declare it, then it's very probable that your are working with child scopes/inheritance

Take a look at [Scope inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)